# How to show full content of text file with dialog --checklist

Tags: bash

My text file is:

```
1 2000 4000 6000    
2 3000 5000 7000    
3 8000 9000 0000   
.
.
.
```

or any information that the user will input

How can I show the full content of the text file with the dialog `--checklist`, please?

The expected output:

```
[ ] 1 2000 4000 6000  
  
[ ] 2 3000 5000 7000

[ ] 3 8000 9000 0000 
.

.
.
.
```

Answer (score 1):

Use an array to store all the entries of the checklist (And the other arguments for it):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

# Initial arguments: header-text height width list-height
declare -a args=("Make your selection(s)" 20 70 20)

# Add each line to the checklist, using the first column as the tag
while read -r tag item; do
    # tag item status
    args+=("$tag" "$item" off)
done < list.txt

# And display the dialog and capture the output
tmpfile=$(mktemp)
dialog --separate-output --checklist "${args[@]}" 2>"$tmpfile"
readarray -t selected <"$tmpfile"
rm -f -- "$tmpfile"

# And show the user what they picked
printf "Your selections: "
printf "%s " "${selected[@]}"
printf "\n"
```

Comment: Nicely done.  Tried with `awk` to build the  `tag` `item` `status` list in a command substitution and there was no way to avoid word-splitting of the 2nd-4th fields without joining by `'_'` after `awk` separated the fields in the text file. (looked fine, but was hackish...)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
#!/bin/bash

datafile="list.txt"

# Check if the file exists
if [[ ! -f "$datafile" ]]
then
    echo "ERROR: file >>$datafile<< does not exist."
    exit 1
fi

choices="dialog --checklist \"Title\" 20 100 100 "
# Read the file line per line
while IFS= read -r line
do
    # skip empty lines
    if [[ "$line" == "" ]]
    then
        continue
    fi
    # first element of the line is the id
    idnumber=${line%% *}
    # keep the rest of the line, without the id, and add quotes
    restofline="'$(echo "$line" | cut -d' ' -f2-)'"

    # Add these to the choices
    choices="$choices $idnumber $restofline off"
done < "$datafile"

# DEBUG echo ">>$choices<<"

eval $choices
```

- `dialog` expects:

  ```
  <Title> <height> <width> <list height> <tag1> <item1> <status1> <tag2> <item2> <status2> ...
  ```
- status can be `on` or `off`, to specify whether that tag is to be selected or not when the dialog is created.  Here it is set `off` by default.
- in your data, you have `1 2000 4000 6000`.  Therefore the tag is the first element (here 1) and the rest are the item (here "2000 4000 6000").
- to allow many words in the item, you must enclose them in quotes.
- this explains why I extract the first word in the line for the tag, and the rest are surrounded by quotes.
- each line in list.txt is transformed into another dialog tag-item-status element.
- Obviously you will have to play with the parameters and title to configure `dialog` like you need it.

Comment: `choices="$choices` use bash array. Do not use eval. Eval is unnecessary here anyway, it could just be removed, just `$choices`. Check scripts with shellcheck.